# Convert a string vector into a formula style, removing **""*

Tags: r, string, dplyr, formula

I want to convert the following string vector:

```
variables <- c("temperature", "rain", "sun_days", "season")
```

into the following formula:

```
formula <- pred ~ treatment*(temperature + rain + sun_days + season)
```

The way I converted the **variables** vector into a formula style is the following:

```
predictors <- paste0(variables, collapse = "+")
```

However, it does not make the trick when I write the formula in the following way:

```
formula <- pred ~ treatment*(variables)
```

It doesn't work because of the **""** that characterises the string vector.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
formula <- as.formula(
  paste("pred ~ treatment * (", paste(variables, collapse = "+"), ")")
)
```

Result:

```
> formula
pred ~ treatment * (temperature + rain + sun_days + season)
```